# configure git ignore file to exclude files of certain mime-type

Tags: git, mime-types

Would it be possible to configure git ignore for a particular mime-type?
I am interested in configuring git ignore file to make it NOT pick up elf executable files.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git ignore is based on recognising patterns in the filename.

MIME types are determined by some metadata, for example the `Content-Type` header of an HTTP request. This metadata is not present in the filename alone, so I think there is no simple way to do what you are trying to achieve.

The best you could do is ignore the known file types such as `.axf, .bin, .elf, .o, .prx, .puff, .ko, .mod and .so` (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)), but in the case of no file extension, I think your only options would be to ignore the entire output directory or known filenames.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is that on linux boxes, when we compile a binary - it creates executable files without any extensions unlike the case in windows (where we have .exe), so unless we make a check on a file, we cannot know if they an elf file or not. Wish we had something for this.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, I think common options are to compile to a known output directory that you ignore, or blacklist the known executable names.

Comment: I think I will accept your answer now as I looked further into it and couldn't find anything else. Wish we had something for it.